# How to show an ad every ...seconds in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently started using unity3d so I don't know every thing about it.
How can I show ADS every ... seconds in unity?

 I want to show an ad every 300 / 500 seconds any help? (Ps. I don't have any code)

```
          using UnityEngine;
        using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

        public class UnityAdsExample : MonoBehaviour
        {
          public void ShowRewardedAd()
          {
            if (Advertisement.IsReady("rewardedVideo"))
            {
              var options = new ShowOptions { resultCallback = HandleShowResult };
              Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideo", options);
            }
          }

          private void HandleShowResult(ShowResult result)
          {
            switch (result)
            {
              case ShowResult.Finished:
                Debug.Log("The ad was successfully shown.");
                //
                // YOUR CODE TO REWARD THE GAMER
                // Give coins etc.
                break;
              case ShowResult.Skipped:
                Debug.Log("The ad was skipped before reaching the end.");
                break;
              case ShowResult.Failed:
                Debug.LogError("The ad failed to be shown.");
                break;
            }
          }
        }
```

Thnx :)

Comment: Hi @Cypher, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: oh i already tried a few codes but none really didn't work so that's why i didn't have a code, thank you luis!

Comment: In that case you should always said that in the question and put your attempts can help a lot of people to provide a great answer. It also help reviewers _(like me in this case)_ to separate **good questions** from **too board**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to decide which ads source you will use(Admob,UnityAds etc).Than you have to implement proper ads load mechanism but that may change to ads source you decided to use (In Admob you have to import Admob's unity library).

If you want to do something in every x seconds you can use Coroutines described in link below:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

But as I sad first you have to learn how to get ads from ads sources.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, sorry.

Code I used:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class Ad : MonoBehaviour
{
float timer;
void Start()
{
    Advertisement.Initialize("OWN GAME CODE(UNITY)"); //Remember to edit
}

void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    ShowAd();
}

public void ShowAd()
{
    if (Advertisement.IsReady() && timer <= 0)
    {
        Advertisement.Show();
        timer = 300.0f; //Amount of seconds // remember to set it to 300.0f
    }
}}
```